# The sum to n terms of the series $\frac{1}{\sqrt 1+\sqrt 3} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 5} ....$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

The common difference is *d*

Multiplying and dividing by d

$$\frac 1d [\frac{3-1}{\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 1} + \frac{5-3}{\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 3}....]$$
$$=\frac 1d [\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 1 + \sqrt 5 - \sqrt 3........\sqrt {2n-1} - \sqrt {2n-2}]$$
$$\frac 1d [\sqrt {2n-1} - \sqrt 1]$$

Since n term will be $$a_n=1+(n-1)2$$
$$=2n-1$$

Final answer 
$$\frac 12 [\sqrt{2n-1}-1]$$

This isn’t the right answer however. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the difference is common?  $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{3}} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}} \ne \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}}$$

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing, but the correct answer is $$\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-1}{2}\,.$$  (Maybe Robert Israel is right, you are wrongly assuming that some sequence, which I am not quite sure which, is an arithmetic sequence.)

Comment: Well, I will add more details

Comment: It’s up there now.

Comment: You have been recently asking lot of solutions to really trivial questions (most of which looks like school homework). It would be appreciated if you try to properly solve and give time to them before asking.

Comment: Yeah they are homework. But you must notice that I am typing down my entire solutions. I generally collect all my problems and ask them at once, so you are seeing a sudden influx of question, most of may seem trivial to you. Perhaps you are older than me, so naturally you find them easy

Comment: I don't think you have correctly identified the $n$-th term of your original sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do is mostly right, though I do not follow what you mean by "common difference", and you may not have determined the last term correctly.

First, let us figure what would be the correct $n$-th term.
The first term is $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt1+\sqrt3}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\cdot1-1}+\sqrt{2\cdot1+1}}\ $.
The second term is $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt3 +\sqrt5}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cdot2-1}+\sqrt{2\cdot2+1}}\ $.
From this one would conclude that the $n$-th term is 
$\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}$.

Multiplying and dividing by $2$ you get:
$\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt1+\sqrt3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3+\sqrt5}+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}=$

$=\displaystyle\frac12\bigl[\frac2{\sqrt3+\sqrt1}+\frac2{\sqrt5+\sqrt3}+\cdots+\frac2{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}\bigr]=$

$=\displaystyle\frac12\bigl[\frac{3-1}{\sqrt3+\sqrt1}+\frac{5-3}{\sqrt5+\sqrt3}+\cdots+\frac{2n+1-(2n-1)}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}\bigr]=$

$=\displaystyle\frac12\bigl[\sqrt3-\sqrt1+\sqrt5-\sqrt3+\cdots+\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}\bigr]=$

$=\displaystyle\frac12\bigl[\sqrt{2n+1}-1\bigr]$
(which as already indicated in other comments and answers is the right answer).

So things you didn't do right: (1) not clear what is that $d$ and why you don't simply multiply and divide by $2$, and (2) you did not write the $n$-th term correctly, making two mistakes (a) you ended with $\displaystyle\sqrt{2n-1}$ instead of $\displaystyle\sqrt{2n+1}$, and (b) 
the terms you wrote $\displaystyle\sqrt{2n-1}-\sqrt{2n-2}$, the difference between $\displaystyle2n-1$ and $\displaystyle2n-2$ is only $1$ when it is supposed to be $\displaystyle2$. That is, instead of $\displaystyle\sqrt{2n-1}-\sqrt{2n-2}$ you should have written $\displaystyle\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}$.

I think you could have corrected these mistakes yourself if you carefully inspected what you wrote, each step, each detail. You did have the correct idea.

Answer (score 7):

You can rewrite it as follows:

$$S_n=\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{1}}{3-1}+\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{5-3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}}{2n+1-(2n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{2n+1})$$

It's a telescopic sum, consecutive elements are cancelling: $S_n=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{2i+1}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{2i+1})$

Comment: May I ask how you got $\sqrt {2n+1}$? I too solved it in my solution, but I have $\sqrt {2n-1}$ instead

Comment: Take a look at the bottom formula: it cancells almost entirely, the only thing, thats left is positive for $i=n$ and negative for $i=0$, so $\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2*0+1}=\sqrt{2n+1}-1$

Comment: Is i supposed to be a complex number, or is just some random variable?

Comment: Just an iterator. Check the sum limits.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is equivalent to

$$-\frac12 +\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac{\sqrt5}2-\frac{\sqrt5}2+\dots$$